# I'm having trouble plotting date and two pieces of data on same graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've used the code below to make simple plots of date and one piece of data. Now I would like to plot two pieces of data on the one graph.

**Data** *(m/d/y,data0,data1)*

```
6/28/13,256,503
6/29/13,74,274
6/30/13,62,376
7/1/13,159,222
7/2/13,105,173
```

I've tried to amend this code to read in the extra float but I just don't know the syntax well enough and it returns an error. I've also searched through SOF and can't find an example that helps.

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

arch = 'myfile.csv'
data = csv.reader(open(arch))

data = [(dt.datetime.strptime(item, "%m/%d/%y"), float(value)) for item, value in data]
data.sort()
[x, y] = zip(*data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, color='blue')

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.title('posts')

plt.xlabel('Date Range 28.06.2013 to 28.03.2014')
plt.ylabel('y')

fig.set_facecolor('white')

plt.show()
```

With date and one piece of data I get lovely results

[image: simple working graph]

Could someone amend this code to plot the 2x data against the date please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these changes and you will be good to go:

```
data = [(dt.datetime.strptime(item, "%b/%d/%y"), float(v1), float(v2)) for (item, v1, v2) in data]
data.sort()
[x, y, z] = zip(*data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, color='blue')
ax.plot(x, z, color='red')
```

Basically you have three fields in your csv file, while your `data=` line only takes two.

Also you need to format `xaxis`, by adding:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m/%d/%y"))
```

[image]

You may want to try `pandas`, which will simplify this operation into just two lines:

```
import pandas as pd
DF=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None, names=['Time', 'x1', 'x2'])
DF.plot(x='Time', y=['x1', 'x2'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much CT Zhu. The line I was missing **ax.plot(x, z, color='red')** now makes sense.